# Sort a list "2D"

Tags: java, list, sorting, compare

I have a Person class :

```
public class Person {
    public Integer id;
    public Integer lame;
    public String position;

    public Person(Integer id, Integer lame, String position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lame = lame;
        this.position = position;
    }


    public String getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

And, I have list of Person like this :

```java
List<Person>list = new ArrayList<Person>();
list.add(new Person (85785,1,"R01C01"));
list.add(new Person (6789,1,"R05C01"));
list.add(new Person (67866,1,"R02C02"));
list.add(new Person (767867,1,"R04C01"));
list.add(new Person (10,1,"R02C01"));
list.add(new Person (1687, 1, "R03C02"));
list.add(new Person (3542,1,"R04C02"));
list.add(new Person (35433,1,"R05C02"));
list.add(new Person (435434,1,"R03C01"));
list.add(new Person (333,1,"R01C02"));
```

*(I specify that the sizes of the lines (R) and the columns (C) can vary. But I don't think that will pose a problem concerning the same sorting)*

I would like to sort the items in this list as follows:

- Plate
- Row (R)
- Column (C)

the list should be sorted by position like this :

[image]

I tried to use the "Comparing" function :

```java
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        String positionO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position
        String positionO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position
        return positionO1.compareTo(positionO2);
    }
});

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        String positionO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position 
        String positionO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position
        return positionO1.compareTo(positionO2);
    }
});

for (Person p: list) {
    System.out.println(p.getPosition());
}
```

But I get the following result.... :

- R01C01
- R01C02
- R02C01
- R02C02
- R03C01
- R03C02
- R04C01
- R04C02
- R05C01
- R05C02

Can you help me please.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `sort` twice, you don't tell the program to sort on **both** criteria, but one the first one **then** on the second one. That means the first sort is discarded by the second one.

You need to use both criteria in the same `Comparator`:

The first criteria is the first 2 digits. If those are different, return the result. But if they are equals then you compare the following digits.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        String positionAO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position 
        String positionAO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position

        int firstCriteria = positionAO1.compareTo(positionAO2);

        if (firstCriteria != 0) {
            return firstCriteria;
        }

        String positionBO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position
        String positionBO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position
        return positionBO1.compareTo(positionBO2); // return the second criteria
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the collection twice with two different comparators, what you'll get is a list sorted by the second comparator you used.
You need to create one comparator that will compare two persons by all the criterias you want.
something like this, which will first compare columns and if they are identical will compare rows (I'll leave the inner details to you):

```
new Comparator<Person>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
     int columnBasedCompare = compareColumn(o1, o2);
     return columnBaseCompare == 0 ? compareRow(o1,o2) : columnBaseCompare;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys

I thought that the second sort was added to the first ..

So the solution is as follows:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                /*String positionAO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position
                String positionAO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position*/

                String positionBO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position
                String positionBO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position

                int firstCriteria = positionBO1.compareTo(positionBO2);

                if (firstCriteria != 0) {
                    return firstCriteria;
                }

                /*String positionBO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position
                String positionBO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(4,6);    // "C" position*/
                String positionAO1 = o1.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position
                String positionAO2 = o2.getPosition().substring(1,3);   // "R" position
                return positionAO1.compareTo(positionAO2); // return the second criteria
            }
        });
```

(I reversed the column / row sorting because the result was the same as earlier)